# Sonarqube’s UndocumentedApi rendered useless?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I recently updated the Java pugin in our SonarQube installation. I now have many, many instances of UndocumentedApi reported.

I do not agree that every parameter on a public function needs to be documented, neither return values. (Often the text says it all, for Spring MVC controllers the arguments are repetetive and blatantly obvious etc.) I do, however, agree that every public method needs to be documented. (This question is not about whether my opinion here is sensible.)

I only see the option to either live with > 1000 warning that hide the more important issues or disable that check, losing this analysis. Have I overlooked an option? Is there a more configurable plugin?

Comment: Which ruleset produces the warnings? PMD? Checkstyle? I'm pretty sure checkstyle has seperate rules for having a comment on public methods in general and having to document each parameter in that comment.

Comment: It’s Squid. There are three Checkstyle rules (separate for type, variable, method), but they are marked as deprecated.

Comment: Hmm, don't know about Squid. I use Checkstyle for that but I never noticed deprecated rules. Can you find out what rules to use instead? If something is deprecated it's normally replaced ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Switch Off Violations plugin to tune your analysis and remove the noise. From what I understand, you could deactivate this UndocumentedApi rule on Spring classes as it is not relevant in this case. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Switch+Off+Violations+Plugin.

Comment: This looks like a cool plugin. However, I do not see a way to automatically exclude all Spring controllers with the rules that are documented there. Furthermore, these Spring controllers are just one example where documenting parameters is noise, there are many more. We simply do not want to be that strict, considering that we do not write a library for public access by millions.

Comment: What are exactly those Spring controllers? Classes following a naming convention \*SpringControllers.java? Classes that are always stored in specific packages \*\*/mySpringControllers/**/*.java?

Comment: No specific package, and yes, the convention is to name them `…Controller`; the real criterion (for us) is that they are annotated with `@Controller`, luckily we don’t use XML for that.

Comment: Then, you should set the "Multi-criteria exclusion patterns" property to something like *Controller ; squid:UndocumentedApi ; *